# Is there any way to put double quotes in user snippets body?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Like FOR C PROGRAMMING When we want to print something we need to put double quotes in the print function for format specifier SO I want the double quotes in my user snippets, but I am unable to do that as the error I think is because of snippets can only have one pair double quotes.
CAN SOMEONE PLEASE HELP ME OUT WITH THIS

[image: I am getting this error]

Comment: Welcome. In order to salvage this question, I request that you produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (as code, not as an image) containing only C code. As it currently stands, I look at this code you've shown us and it's not C (and is also in image form?! Why?) but you're asking about C... ‍♂️ Utterly baffling, and I reckon this can't/won't be answered in this current form.

Comment: You can output double-quotes by 'escaping' the quote marks like this: `printf("\"double-quoted\"");`

Comment: just like you need to escape the backslash with a backslash inside a JSON string

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the double quotes with `\` symbol. Just replace `"` with `\"`